# Auto Accept Outlook Invitations by User

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

Is it possible to automatically accept outlook meeting invitations by sender?

I can only find a way to do it for all invitations.

Answer (score 1):

Please read this and let me know if this what you are looking for. It's "Direct Booking" of ressources.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/291616/en-us

**How to Define a Resource Account**

1. Create a new e-mail account for the
   resource by using the Microsoft
   Exchange Server Administrator
   account.
2. Start Outlook by using the
   new resource account to create the
   default folders in the mailbox on
   the server.
3. On the Tools menu,
   click Options.
4. Click Calendar
   Options, and then click Resource
   Scheduling.
5. Click to select all
   three Meeting Request options, and
   then click Set Permissions.
6. Click
   Add to add the users that will be
   allowed to use the resource.
7. Assign at least Author permissions for each
   user.
8. Click OK to close the dialog
   boxes, and then quit Outlook.

**How to Direct-Book an Appointment to the Resource**

You can book the resource at the same time that you create the meeting. You can view the free/busy information of the resource account in the Plan a Meeting form.

Use the following steps to invite attendees and resources to a meeting:

1. Click Calendar.
2. On the Actions menu, click Plan A Meeting.
3. In the Plan A Meeting dialog box, click Invite Others.
4. In the Type name or Select from List box, type the name of the person or resource that you want at the meeting.
5. For each name entered, click either Required, Optional, or Resources.

NOTE: As a rule, users should be invited as Required or Optional, and resources should be invited as Resources. The meeting invitation is addressed with the required and optional attendees appearing in the To box on the Appointment tab, and the resources appear in the Location box.

6: Click OK, and then use the scroll bars to view the free/busy time for invitees.

7: Click a time when all invitees are available. You can use AutoPick to find the next available free time for all invitees.

8: Click Make Meeting.

> Note When you direct book a resource, you update the free/busy information for the resource.

Answer (score 0):

> You need to install the "[Auto Accept Agent](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=3d0884e6-c603-491d-bf57-acf03e046bfe&displaylang=en)" on the exchange server where user's mailboxes are hosted. you will have to manually register mailboxes with auto accept agent. It will not pickup the mailbox automatically. You also need to give atleast "reviewer" permissions to default on every user's personal calendar for "Auto Accept Agent" to process the meeting invites.

The Auto-Request Agent isn't designed for use with individual mailboxes (it's for "Resource" mailboxes such as a meeting room).

For individual users, it's generally not a good idea to use auto-accept as it can cause problems with the way meeting requests are created.  Instead, sharing a company-wide calendar would be more effective and easier to manage.  You can either create a separate mailbox for this, or use the Company Calendar that's already configured in SharePoint (http://companyweb).

More info on meeting requests: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/HA011276781033.aspx

Sharing a calendar via SharePoint:  http://office.microsoft.com/training/training.aspx?AssetID=RC011187001033&pid=CR061832721033

Comment: A shared calendar isn't appropriate in this scenario. Are you suggesting what I wanted to do isn't possible. If there are no inbuilt settings for this would it be possible to write a VB macro to do it for me?

Comment: Ok for Sharepoint. Give it a try with the AutoAcceptAgent.

Comment: Looking for something client side if possible?

Comment: Do you have administrative rights to apply it on exchange?

Comment: We don't have access to exchange. This is why I need it to be client side.

Comment: Ok, let me do some search